# Angular 2 - get the right object from an array of objects

Tags: angular

I got a list of `Peoples` (people object) from my json API and I saved it in a variable accessed via `this.people`.

I need to access the person where his pivot object `age = 15` assuming there is only one pivot object defind with age of 15.

1. Can I access this specific object with angular 2?
2. If not, will I have to change my API to make a new request for it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a custom pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe {
  transform(val) {
    return val.filter((elt) => elt.age === 15);
  }
}
```

and use it this way:

```
{{people | filter}}
```

Don't forget to add your pipe into the `pipes` attribute of the component where you want to use it:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  pipes: [ FilterPipe ]
})
```

You could make this pipe a bit generic with parameters:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe {
  transform(val, params) {
    var field = params[0];
    var fieldValue = params[1];
    return val.filter((elt) => elt[field] === fieldValue);
  }
}
```

and use it this way:

```
{{people | filter:age:15}}
```

Comment: What's the "elt" variable?

Comment: `elt` is an element of array. It's provided to the arrow function... The `filter` method iterates over the values of the array.